# Handlebars returning no value but it exists in {{this}}

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, templating

Using Handlebars 4.0.6 and NodeJS 7.4.0, I output the data that my template is receiving using `{{this}}`, which outputs:

```
{ _id: 58a7de1c7275f8208438ae4a,
  author: 589a12b5a08e0c2f24ece4e8,
  dateCreated: 2017-02-18T05:39:40.650Z,
  section: 58a7d57c9ce34527bce7e041,
  slug: 'this-one-will-work',
  title: 'this one will work',
  color: '#d313ff',
  __v: 0,
  fields: 
  [ { fieldId: 58a3cff51da0ea5d00972804,
      fieldSlug: 'color',
      value: '#d313ff',
      _id: 58a7de1c7275f8208438ae4b } ] }
```

However, using `{{color}}` or `{{this.color}}` in the template right below the `{{this}}` doesn't output anything.

I'm getting the data with mongoose in a Promise, then compiling it, the using `res.send()`.

Here's my compiling function:

```
    const Handlebars = require('handlebars');
    const fs = require('fs');
    const path = require('path');

    module.exports = (template, data) =>
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const templateWithFormat = template.endsWith('.hbs') ? template : `${template}.hbs`;
        const templatePath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'templates', templateWithFormat);

        fs.readFile(templatePath, 'utf-8', (err, file) => {
          if (err) reject(err);

          const compiled = Handlebars.compile(file);
          const html = compiled(data);

          resolve(html);
        });
      });
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I just tried to run this code: http://jsbin.com/goxufawulo/1/edit?js and it renders color as '#d313ff'. I use Node.js 6.9 and handlebars 4.0.6.
Could you provide a runnable chunk of code that give you desirable output?

Comment: I'm using Node 7.4.0 and Handlebars 4.0.6. I'm really not doing much that isn't in your JSBin, so maybe its just the Node version? I'll try it on a different version when I get a chance.

Comment: just tested with Node 7.4.0. Something different causes the issue.

Comment: @AntonioNarkevich Thanks for doing that; I've updated my answer with some code from my environment

Comment: I suggest you to console.log(data.color) before compiling, also do the same with a template (if it was read properly). Then I'd suggest to try calling data.toObject() before passing it to compiled as mongoose wraps the objects.

Comment: @AntonioNarkevich I think I've figured it out, and its basically what you've suggested there; I made my request use `{ lean: true }` to remove Mongoose's wrapping and it works now. toObject() sounds better though, thank you! Can you write that as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have a problem if you pass a mongoose model object to Handlebars.
(because mongoose wraps an object and adds getters/setters for the properties)

To solve this issue please try running your query with `{lean: true}` or call `modelObj.toObject()` before sending it to handlebars.

Comment: Thanks for your help!